# How to make this code working once?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog

I need to make this part of code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    openingCount++;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_background);  
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    // Create the adView.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (openingCount == 1){
        AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select A Server:");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        arrayAdapter.add("North America");
        arrayAdapter.add("EU West");
        arrayAdapter.add("EU North-East");
        arrayAdapter.add("LatinoAmerica Sur");
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        selectedLink = siteList[which];
                        selectedServer = serverList[which];
                        ParsingPaginaWeb parsing = new ParsingPaginaWeb();
                        parsing.execute("");
                    }
                });
        builderSingle.show();
    }protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    openingCount++;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_background);  
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    // Create the adView.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (openingCount == 1){
        AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select A Server:");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        arrayAdapter.add("North America");
        arrayAdapter.add("EU West");
        arrayAdapter.add("EU North-East");
        arrayAdapter.add("LatinoAmerica Sur");
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        selectedLink = siteList[which];
                        selectedServer = serverList[which];
                        ParsingPaginaWeb parsing = new ParsingPaginaWeb();
                        parsing.execute("");
                    }
                });
        builderSingle.show();
    }
```

running once. I want that the Dialog shows up only when the app is launched, but everytime I start a child Activity of this one, and I press back, the dialog shows up...

How can I fix this? I tried a lot of "tricks", but none worked...

Thanks!

Comment: save this count in sharedpreference insted of simply increment

Comment: Your `openingCount` will always be 0 unless you save is in `sharedPreferences`.

Comment: Would you really want to ask for the server every time the app launches?

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/    this is also one one best tutorial

Comment: the notion of app being launched is quite fuzzy in android, but I guess a static boolean set and tested would come quite close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to save a value that indicates whether the dialog has previously been shown.

SharedPreferences is a good choice for this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html